# Javascript URL has illegal characters in it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with Cloudinary, an image hosting service. I am currently storing my URLs as strings such as: `http://res.cloudinary.com/dhulxtn8x/image/upload/v1400107030/zz06phflcmal8xmpg2hh.jpg`

I need to add a setting parameter to the URL, so I am splitting it, inserting the setting and then joining it back. However, I am getting illegal characters when I combined it back together. Here is my code:

```
var fileSplit = file.split('/');
var uploadUrl = fileSplit.splice(0, 6).join('/');
var uploadId = fileSplit.splice(0, 8).join('/');
var thumbnailSetting = '​/c_fill,h_150,w_100';
var uploadUrl = uploadUrl + thumbnailSetting + uploadId;
```

The `console.log()` says: `http://res.cloudinary.com/dhulxtn8x/image/upload​/c_fill,h_150,w_100v1400107030/zz06phflcmal8xmpg2hh.jpg` however my console also then says:

`GET http://res.cloudinary.com/dhulxtn8x/image/upload%E2%80%8B/c_fill,h_150,w_100v1400107030/zz06phflcmal8xmpg2hh.jpg 400 (Bad Request)`

You can see the illegal characters after `upload`. How can I get rid of these without removing characters that I might need.

Comment: Here the answer: [urldecode](http://urldecode.org/?decode=http%3A%2F%2Fres.cloudinary.com%2Fdhulxtn8x%2Fimage%2Fupload%25E2%2580%258B%2Fc_fill%2Ch_150%2Cw_100v1400107030%2Fzz06phflcmal8xmpg2hh.jpg)

Comment: That's not an answer at all..

Comment: How are you getting the value for thumbnail setting. Is it really the way you have it with a hard-coded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thumbnailSetting = '​/c_fill,h_150,w_100';
thumbnailSetting = encodeURI(thumbnailSetting );
```

That will take care of it for you.

**EDIT**

You have an invisible character in this line, right after the opening quote:

```
'​/c_fill,h_150,w_100';
```

I noticed it while making this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fLX44/). I left it so you can see. That code was copied directly from your question. Remove it and you should be good.

Comment: I still have the illegal characters in the URL string after doing this, however now the initial `console.log()` is showing the illegal characters.